# DNS and name server in centos 6.3 64 bit is not pinged out side

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, bind, nameserver

I got a problem with centOS 6.3 64-bit. I want to setup my nameserver with bind here. I am listing all my configuration

```
[root@izyon92 ~]# cat/etc/hosts
--------------

127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
182.19.26.92 izyon92.zyonize1.com izyon92


[root@izyon92 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network
---------------------------------------------
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=izyon92.zyonize1.com
GATEWAY=182.19.26.89

[root@izyon92 ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
--------------------------------------------
# Generated by NetworkManager
search zyonize1.com
nameserver 182.19.26.92

[root@izyon92 ~]# cat /etc/named.conf
--------------------------------------------
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//

options {

        #listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; }; 

        listen-on-v6 port 53 { none; };

        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query     { 182.19.26.92; };
        recursion yes;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";

[root@izyon92 ~]# cat /etc/named.rfc1912.zones
--------------------------------------------------
// named.rfc1912.zones:
//
// Provided by Red Hat caching-nameserver package
//
// ISC BIND named zone configuration for zones recommended by
// RFC 1912 section 4.1 : localhost TLDs and address zones
// and http://www.ietf.org/internet-drafts/draft-ietf-dnsop-default-local-zones-02.txt
// (c)2007 R W Franks
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//

zone "localhost.localdomain" IN {
        type master;
        file "named.localhost";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "localhost" IN {
        type master;
        file "named.localhost";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "named.loopback";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "named.loopback";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "0.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "named.empty";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "zyonize1.com" {
        type master;
        file "/var/named/zyonize.com.hosts";
};


[root@izyon92 ~]# cat /var/named/zyonize.com.hosts
---------------------------------------------------------
$ttl 38400

zyonize1.com.    IN      SOA     182.19.26.92. dev\.izyon.gmail.com. (

                        1347436958

                        10800

                        3600

                        604800

                        38400 )

zyonize1.com.    IN      NS      182.19.26.92.

zyonize1.com.    IN      A       182.19.26.92

www.zyonize1.com.        IN      A       182.19.26.92

izyon92.zyonize1.com.    IN      A       182.19.26.92



I have disabled selinux and stopped iptables.

dig and nslookup is working fine in the same machine 


[root@izyon92 ~]# dig zyonize1.com
----------------------------------------

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.10.rc1.el6_3.2 <<>> zyonize1.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55751
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;zyonize1.com.                  IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
zyonize1.com.           38400   IN      A       182.19.26.92

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
zyonize1.com.           38400   IN      NS      182.19.26.92.

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 182.19.26.92#53(182.19.26.92)
;; WHEN: Fri Sep 14 00:09:19 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 72


[root@izyon92 ~]# nslookup zyonize1.com
----------------------------------------------
Server:         182.19.26.92
Address:        182.19.26.92#53

Name:   zyonize1.com
Address: 182.19.26.92
```

But here is the problem I am facing, I have windows machine, to test this dns and nameserver I set the first IPv4 DNS server to 182.19.26.92. Here is the details

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix: 
Description: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Physical Address: ‎14-FE-B5-9F-3A-A8
DHCP Enabled: No
IPv4 Address: 192.168.2.50
IPv4 Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
IPv4 Default Gateway: 192.168.2.1
IPv4 DNS Servers: 182.19.26.92, 182.19.95.66
IPv4 WINS Server: 
NetBIOS over Tcpip Enabled: Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address: fe80::45cc:2ada:c13:ca42%16
IPv6 Default Gateway: 
IPv6 DNS Server:
```

when I am pining from this machine it is not finding the server.

Where as in another server with another live IP with Fedora ping is working fine.

Comment: Are the Windows machines and Fedora machines on the same network?  Could be a routing issue.

Comment: Yes they are in same network

Answer (score 0):

I have some questions, but I don't have enough rep to comment yet, so I'll propose it as an answer with room for followup.

First, I think you're having a network issue, not a dns issue. If you're unable to ping the ip (182.19.26.92), then you probably have a network connectivity issue on the 182.19.26.92 server. I'd be curious to see the output of `ifconfig` and to know if this is behind a NAT. It might also be helpful to see the output of the interface config files: `for x in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-* ; do echo $x: ; cat $x ; done`

Also, (probably not related to your current issue, but an issue nonetheless) your zone file /var/named/zyonize.com.hosts looks incorrect to me. Here's a diff showing the changes I'd recommend:

```
--- zonefile.orig   2013-08-22 15:16:08.000000000 -0400
+++ zonefile.new    2013-08-22 15:17:02.000000000 -0400
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 $ttl 38400

-zyonize1.com.    IN      SOA     182.19.26.92. dev\.izyon.gmail.com. (
+zyonize1.com.    IN      SOA     ns1.zyonize1.com dev\.izyon.gmail.com. (

                         1347436958

@@ -12,7 +12,8 @@

                         38400 )

-zyonize1.com.    IN      NS      182.19.26.92.
+zyonize1.com.      IN  NS  ns1.zyonize1.com.
+ns1.zyonize1.com.  IN  A   182.19.26.92

 zyonize1.com.    IN      A       182.19.26.92
```

You'll note the NS record should point to a name, with an associated glue record, not directly to an IP.

Comment: Yes, the alternative to the answer from @piernov (better if there is truly no answer whatsoever) is network/firewall. And while most likely separate from this particular problem you're absolutely right that both the SOA MNAME and NS record values do refer to names and nothing else. Well spotted :)

Answer (score 0):

named should listen on all IPv4 address :

```
listen-on port 53 { any; };
```

And with :

```
allow-query     { 182.19.26.92; };
```

you only allow queries from your server's IP address. You might want to allow queries from everywhere :

```
allow-query     { any;};
```

Comment: While you have most likely correctly identified the problem the proposed solution is not good. `allow-query {any;};` in combination with `recursion yes;` is not(!) a good combination for a publicly accessible machine! Please look at the [documentation of how the `allow-*` default values depend on the values of the others](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.9/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#options).  (If one overrides `allow-query` this also affects `allow-recursion`!)